# Hide collapsible image into just one grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

as the title says I need to hide the collapsible image from one grid (I have many in the same web), and I cannot simply change the css because then every grid in my web would do the same, I want just that grid to have no background image.

I have tried to create a css class with `background-image: none` and change the bodyCssClass, baseCls, cls configs, but I don't obtain the expected behaviour.

Any idea?

EDIT 1:

**GridPanel code:**

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    id: "gridPanel1",
    disableSelection: true,
    frame: true,
    title: "Centers",
    //autoHeight: true,
    height: 415,
    width: 500,
    store: store,
    colModel: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel(items),
    ctCls: 'noCollapsable',
    view: groupingVi,
    sm: selectionMod
});
```

**css:**

```
.noCollapsable{
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

EDIT 2:

Yes! It's exactly like that example ( http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/grid/groupgrid.html ), but the background image it's in the

```
 <div class="x-grid-group-title">Cuisine: CountryX (Y Items)</div>
```

and I don't have idea of how to use the Ext DomHelper or anything to change those divs' css inside this structure:

```
<tr id="gridview-1013-hd-CountryX" class="x-grid-group-hd x-grid-group-hd-collapsed">
   <td class="x-grid-cell" colspan="2" style="padding-left:0px;">
      <div class="x-grid-cell-inner">
         <div class="x-grid-group-title">Cuisine: Country X (Y Items)</div>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

In which I could use first tr's id to distingish from the other grids, but as I said, I don't know how to access those divs

Answer (score 0):

can you post some code as there will be better way to achieve this. But as a guess.

What happens when you assign the following to your grid

```
baseCls: 'myClass';
```

and then in your css.

```
.myClass{background-image: none !important;}
```

Comment: With this solution (changing `#myClass` to `.myClass`) all the background images disapear, including the one I don't want, but also the blue one that is under the title, so the panel doesn't look really like a panel :S

Comment: i'm a bit confused by when you say " image from one grid" do you have multiple grids on this page or are you referring to rows. Also are you aware of ext "renderer". ie see this grid how it has images in the grid. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/grid/array-grid.html this example is a little complex. I can post some more simple code if you think this would help.

Comment: I have more than one grid, I don't mean rows, maybe the explanation is not really good.
I want to not show the [+] or [-] symbol that is displayed adjacently to the `groupTextTpl`.
The example has images but the problem is that the images that I want to remove are added by Ext Js, they are not icons inserted by me.

Comment: aah, do you mean something like. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/grid/groupgrid.html each grid has it's own id ie #gridview-1013-bd-American .noCollapsable. Appreciate it's hacky.

Comment: I'll put the reply in the main post to make it easier to understand.

Comment: i see, so if you change the background on x-grid-group-title it effect the [+] as well. tricky... You could experiment with background position as oppose to background:none;. Or what if via js you find where not #gridview-1013-hd-CountryX .x-grid-group-title and add the class .showBackgroundImage. ie add the class that displays the background image.